# append list to a list

Tags: r

I know this is a really noob question, but how do I append a list of dataframes to a dataframe to form a new list, with all the data.frames at the same level in the list?

Some of my attempts:

```
> df <- data.frame(time=1:5)
> df
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
> innerlist <- list(df,df,df)
> innerlist
[[1]]
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5

[[2]]
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5

[[3]]
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5

> outerlist <- list(df,innerlist)
> outerlist
[[1]]
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5

[[2]][[2]]
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5

[[2]][[3]]
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5


> outerlist2 <- c(df,innerlist)
> outerlist2
$time
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5

[[3]]
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5

[[4]]
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5

> outerlist3 <- cbind(df,innerlist)
> outerlist3
  time time time time
1    1    1    1    1
2    2    2    2    2
3    3    3    3    3
4    4    4    4    4
5    5    5    5    5
```

Pretend that all the `df`s are different data-frames.

I want to append df to innnerlist, and get a list with 4 dfs, like:

```
> outerlistmagic <- magic( df, innerlist )
> outerlistmagic
[[1]]
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5

[[2]]
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5

[[3]]
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5

[[4]]
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want `df` to be a list element, you have to wrap it in `list` because a data.frame is a list internally.  For example:

```
append(list(df), innerlist)
c(list(df), innerlist)
```

Comment: Ah, super, thanks!  And you've explained why, so I understand now.

Answer (score 5):

As you recognised, `c` is the correct function to combine lists. While a data.frame is also a list, `c` will remove the data.frame attribute and drop it to a list containing a vector. You can protect this by wrapping it in another list:

```
c(list(df),innerlist)
[[1]]
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5

[[2]]
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5

[[3]]
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5

[[4]]
  time
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
```